# I need to figure out a way to display this on my. I have 2 columns, i Need to be able to display

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, angularjs

This application uses stored procedures, and angular js, as well as jquery. 
Basically I want to get my Category Name to display in my HTML. Currently I can only Display the Category ID. I am using stored procedures.

So I have a categories table and a transaction table. My Transaction Table has a category ID. My Categories table has a Name. 
[Transactions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhuJc.jpg)
[Categories Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUT5x.jpg)

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="even pointer" ng-repeat="transaction in dashboard.transactions">
        <td class=" a-center ">
            <input type="checkbox" class="tableflat">
        </td>
        <td style=" color:green">{{transaction.Description}}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{transaction.Amount}}</td>
        <td class=" "> {{transaction.CategoryId}}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{transaction.Date}}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{transaction.Status}}</td>
        <td class=" last">
            <button data-hover="tooltip" title="Edit" style="height:25px; width:35px" class="fa fa-pencil" ng-click="dashboard.getTransaction1(transaction.Id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".eTrans-modal-sm"></button>
            <button data-hover="tooltip" title="Delete" style="height:25px; width:35px" class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="dashboard.deleteTransaction(transaction.Id)"> </button> <!--data-toggle="modal" data-target=".dTrans-modal-sm">-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Categories Model:

```
    c.cmodel = {
    Id: '',
    HouseholdId: '',
    Name: '',
    ExpenseTF: ''
};
```

Transaction Model:

```
 t.tmodel = {
    Id: '',
    Name: '',
    Amount: '',
    RecAmount: '',
    AccountId: '',
    CategoryId: '',
    Date: '',
    Description: '',
    Status: ''
};
```

Stored Procedure for Getting Transactions from Database. I think this is where I could do some sort of join after i declare a new varible to hold the CategoryName. I think I also need to add a new variable in the transaction model (something like CategoryName) so I can view it in the HTML. Im just not sure how I would Accomplish this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTransactionByAccount]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@accountId int
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * from Transactions where AccountId = @accountId
END
```

How do I get my Category Name to Display instead of Category Id in HTML. Notice, that there is a Ng-Repeat for transactions. The tranactions are brought in when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT trx.*, cat.Name as CategoryName from Transactions trx 
inner join Category cat
on cat.Id = trx.CategoryId
where AccountId = @accountId
```

Then in your HTML you can

```
<td class=" "> {{transaction.CategoryName}}</td>
```

Comment: where would I add this sql statement?

Comment: There are several ways to solve your problem. When you call the stored procedure what happens next in your javascript? Are you mapping the response into the transaction model?

Comment: I guess i need to figure out how to bind the data to the angular model so then it can be displayed. Not sure how to accomplish this.